# Connecting FTP via AWS Lambda

Tags: python, ftp, aws-lambda

I have a python code that runs normally on my local computer but when I try to run in AWS Lambda, a timeout happens when trying to list the files in the directory even though it connects to the directory properly.

```
 ftp = FTP(host,user,password)
 ftp.set_pasv(False)
 print( ftp.cwd(path) )
 print( ftp.retrlines("LIST") )
```

I already tried active and passive mode but both of them don't work. The timeout is already at the max allowed which is 5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your lambda has enough execution time configured to be able to do this operation.
Go to : https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-west-2#/functions?display=list

Change the region to your relevant region.
Select the function, say `FTPLambda`, go to `Configuration` tab and scroll down to the `Advanced Settings`, in here set the  `Timeout` to 5 minutes.
The lambda can be executed at max for five minutes.
Try to run your code and if it runs, adjust the timeout per your needs.